# Degree of differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is the degree of this differential equtaion:
$$(y'')^{2/3}+(y'')^{3/2}=0$$
Solution
$$(y'')^{2/3}=-(y'')^{3/2}$$
Raising both sides with power 6 we get
$$(y'')^4=(y'')^9$$
Now, the degree of highest derivative is both $4$ and $9$.
Then what is the degree? Is it $4$ or $9$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find degree of a differential equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2436288/how-to-find-degree-of-a-differential-equation)

Answer (score 1):

Your equation is not even a differential equation, as only the second derivative but no other derivatives (or the function itself) appears. You can simply integrate twice.

However, in my opinion:

$(y'')^{2/3}=-(y'')^{3/2}$

$(y'')^{3/2}\ (y'')^{-2/3} = (y'')^{5/6}=-1$

so $(y'')^{5/6}+1=0$

Answer (score 0):

I think you mixed up the degree of the differential equation and the degree of the polynomials.

Example,

$$\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}+\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$

is called a third order differential equation. The highest derivative inside the differential equation is $3$. So, it is a third order.

Consider this

$$(\frac{d^3y}{dx^3})^2+y=0$$

This is still considered a third order differential equation.

$$(\frac{dy}{dx})^{10}+y=0$$

This is called the first order differential equation despite that it is raised to the power of 10.

It is very different from the polynomial

Like,

$$y=x^2+x+3$$

This is called a second degree polynomial.

Conclusion:

The highest derivative that exists inside the differential equation let's say 2 is known as the '2' order differential equation.

The highest power that exists inside the polynomial say 10 $(x^{10}) $is called the  10th degree polynomial.

Comment: (dy/dx)^(9)-(dy/dx)^(4) =0 what will be the  degree of this DEQ

Comment: Hint: What is the highest derivative?

Comment: I notice that you mixed up power with the highest derivative.

Comment: the higesht derivative in my question os of order 2 but it has two different exponents, so i have doubt its degree will be 4 or 9?

Comment: It does not depend on exponent. This is not polynomial.

Comment: We look for $$\frac{d^{n}y}{dx^{n}}$$ We call it nth derivative.

Comment: Ok @crazy, then please tell me the degree of given DEQ

Comment: It is second order because its highest derivative is $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$$

Comment: I already knew the order of derivative . Please tell me the degree of  given DEQ

Answer (score 0):

> Polynomials: These are functions which can be written in the form $f(x) = a_0 +a_1x+···+a_dx^d$ for some numbers $a_j, 0 ≤ j ≤ d, d ∈ N$. If $a_d \neq 0$, we say that f is a polynomial of degree d with leading coefficient $a_d$. The maximal domain of any polynomial is R. We say that r is a root or a zero of the polynomial f if $f(r) = 0$.

Where as

> A differential equation is an equation of the form $F(x,y,y',...,y^{n})= 0, x ∈ I$, with the following properties:
>
> (1) n ∈ N is the order of the equation.
>
> (2) F is a given function of n+2 variables.
>
> (3) y is the unknown function of the independent variable x.
>
> (4) I is the interval in which the equation is to hold.

Therefore $\sum^n_{j=1} (y'')^{j}=0$ is still of degree/order 2

(Both extracts are lifted from lecture notes)

Further if were talking about degrees of a differential equation we talk about the highest derivative. If we talk about degrees of a polynomial we talk about the exponent.

Btw for the equation $x^{4}=x^{9}$ where $x=y''$it is not in its simplist form

Thus $1 = x^{5} \Rightarrow x=1$

Comment: what is the degree of given DEQ can you please tell me?

Comment: Yes i can. Its 2

Comment: its order is 2 but degree is 9

Comment: I disagree, by all means explain your rationale. Further have you considered in this instance that order and degree are synonyms for the same thing?

Comment: Further from your own answer, $$(y'')^{4}=(y'')^{9}$$ diving both sides by $(y'')^{4}$ gives $$1=(y'')^{5}$$ thus $$1^{\frac{1}{5}}=((y'')^{5})^{\frac{1}{5}}$$ gives us $$1=y''$$ which immediately  disproves your statement. (As we no longer have any exponents to work with)

Comment: Something unrelated. In your snap for polynomials, can you explain me `...if a_d = 0...`? If `a_d` was 0, then the degree would reduce by one right? For a polynomial of a degree `d` the coefficient of `x^d` should not zero right?

Comment: yes, if we have the polynomial, $f(x) = 9 + 2 \cdot x + 1\cdot x^2 +x^3 \cdot 0$ then the leading co-effecient is 1 and the degree of the polynomial is 2

Answer (score 0):

I dont think any existing answers answer your question .
The degree of the differential equation you asked is 9 because when you try to convert it to a polynomial form , you get the form as $(y")^9-(y")^4=0$ which is similar to finding degree of polynomial $(x)^9-(x)^4=0$ which is clearly 9 .
Hope this answers your doubt .